# MATLAB: Create a block diagonal matrix

Tags: matlab

I have a formula for creating a system of equations in matrix form.and wrote it like below:

```
for i=1:n+1    
    for j=1:n+1    
        t(i)=(1/2)*(1+cos(((2*(n-i)+3)*pi)/(2*(n+1))));    
        y(i,j)=t(i)^(j-1);    
    end    
end
```

now what I have to do is creating a block diagonal matrix with rows of y separately in each block. i mean each row of y that contain powers of just     `t(i)` should repeat three times in each block, then next row be the next block with three rows. like this:

```
T=[y(t1) 0 0;0 y(t1) 0;0 0 y(t1); ... ;y(t n+1) 0 0;0 y(tn+1) 0;0 0 y(tn+1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

So since I can't comment in formated mode I try to interprete your question the following way:

So if

```
 y =

 1     2     
 3     4
```

Interpretation possibility a) is

```
T = 
 1     2     0     0     0     0     3     4     0     0     0     0
 0     0     1     2     0     0     0     0     3     4     0     0
 0     0     0     0     1     2     0     0     0     0     3     4
```

or this b)

```
 T =
 1     2     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     1     2     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     1     2     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     3     4     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     3     4     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     3     4
```

**Solution**
You first create one block i.e.

```
 1     2     0     0     0     0
 0     0     1     2     0     0
 0     0     0     0     1     2
```

by calculating `temp{1} = kron(I, y(1,:))`, where `I = eye(3)`. You then do the same operation for the second row: `temp{2} = kron(I,y(2,:))` and so on. This procedure can be done easily in a for-loop:

```
I = eye(3);
temp = cell(1,size(y,1));
for i = 1:size(y,1)
    temp{i} = kron(I, y(i,:));
end
```

**Option a)**

The result is now just: `[temp{:}]`.

**Option b)**

Here the result is: `blkdiag(temp{:})`

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. but I think I had a mistake for illustrate my problem and unfortunately cant change your answer my self to earn what I want . you know the matrix shold be this form:

a(ti)=[y(ti) 0 0;0 y(ti) 0;0 0 y(ti)]
y=[a1 0 0 … 0;0 a2 … 0; … ;0 0 … an]
you know, in the algorithm that you wrote, every row of y(i) is on the diagonal, but what I need as you see is n matix in a(i) form and then making a block diagonal matrix from them

Comment: I don't understand. Can you edit your question and show us a minimal example?

Comment: Didn't the new answer help?

Comment: I wrote what you wanted in the new answer.can you check it please?

Answer (score 0):

you know, I had a problem for making a system of linear equations.maybe what I wrote above in calculating the `y(i)` just make it difficult for me.
for the example you said, I have this:

```
n=3
```

form equation above:

```
t1=0.0381
t2=0.3087 
t3=0.6913
t4=0.9619
```

now,

```
y(t)=[1 t t^2 t^3 t^4]
```

I mean

```
y(t1)=[1.0000    0.0381    0.0014    0.0001]
y(t2)=[1.0000    0.3087    0.0953    0.0294]
y(t3)=[1.0000    0.6913    0.4780    0.3304]
y(t4)=[1.0000    0.9619    0.9253    0.8901]
```

but, since I couldn't calculate every `y(i)` seperately, wrote it in this form

```
y=[1.0000    0.0381    0.0014    0.0001
    1.0000    0.3087    0.0953    0.0294
    1.0000    0.6913    0.4780    0.3304
    1.0000    0.9619    0.9253    0.8901]
```

now, should have two matrices. one:

```
s=[y(t) 0 0;0 y(t) 0;0 0 y(t)]
r=[s(t1) ... 0; ... ;0 ... s(tn+1)]
```

second:

```
d=[  1    -1     1    -1
     0     2    -8    18
     0     0     8   -48
     0     0     0    32]
k=y*d
u=[0 0 0;0 k 0;0 0 0]
a=[u(t1) ... 0; ... ;0 ... u(tn+1)]
```

and these matrices, r and a, should have `3(n+1)` columns (in this example 12 columns).
I hope it could help

Comment: I think your y matrix in the example is missing the t^4 part. So assuming the matrix y is given with the t.4 part I think your matrix s(t1) for example should have 3 rows and 3*5=15 columns, right? If so your, matrix r should have 3*4= 12 rows and 15*4=60 columns and not 12?
I don't really get how you want s and r look like. Is y(t) the row y(t1) and y(t2) and so on? Because currently I think you might want to have option b) and temp contains the matrices s(t1), s(t2) ....